# Second Navigation Bar

Tags: javascript, scroll, navigation

On this website: http://www.apple.com/ca/ipad-pro/  is the apple website.  On the top of the page you will see two navigation bars.  The top one which is the main one and one underneath it that appears after you scroll down out of vision past the first one.

I understand this process is simple but I can't figure it out!!

Can someone tell me how they made the second one "fixed" AND stay at the top of the page?

When I try this my navigation bar has a space between the top nav and bottom nav.  Pretty sure it's Javascript but I don't know enough. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically going to change the attributes of the secondary nav to `position: fixed; top: 0;` once the user scrolls past a certain point. Check out this tutorial:

https://teamtreehouse.com/community/forum-tip-create-a-sticky-navigation-with-css-and-jquery-2